# Python: Determine value in second list based on first list index

Tags: python

Let's say I have these two arrays:

```
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
u_H = [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]
```

I am given the value: `1.276819`. I would like to find what element in `u_determiner` is closest to `1.276819` and then grab the u_H element at the same index. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `enumerate()` over `u_deteminer`, which will give you the indices and values. Then pass that to `min` with a key that looks for the smallest difference between the value and number. Then use that index to find the value in the other list:

```
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
u_H = [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]

n = 1.276819
i, val = min(enumerate(u_deteminer), key=lambda t: abs(t[1] - n))

# index and value from u_deteminer with the smallest difference
print(i, val) # 5 1.2

# that index in u_H:
print(u_H[i])  # 0.301
```

If you don't actually need the index, you can just zip the lists together and pass that to `min`. This will give you the values from both lists where the `u_deteminer` is closest to your target. Then just use the second:

```
n = 1.276819
D, H = min(zip(u_deteminer, u_H), key=lambda t: abs(t[0] - n) )

print(H) # 0.301
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would do this, but I think you can use numpy to find the nearest number in the first array. As for the second array:

```
u_deteminer = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0]
u_H = [0.368, 0.303, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301, 0.301]

a = u_deteminer.index(1.2)
b = u_H[a]
```